# php-cgi and mysqld failed and recovered notification

Tags: linux, mysql, php

I got these notification emails 2-3 times a day

[image]

I have apache 2.4 mpm_worker and php 7 and suphp handler

I have only wordpress installed

I think this happens when server has 5 or more users online but i am not sure what causes exactly

How can find out what exactly causes mysql and php fail?

Comment: Can you check the log files?

Comment: Which log files ?

Comment: The mysql and php-cgi logs. They should have logged what happened before the crash or even specifically what caused it.